z-index not working as intended, wondering what is causing the issue
I am trying to make a border around a button. This border is supposed to be a gradient so i am simply trying to make a bigger button without functionality underneath the button above. For some reason, no matter what I do they won't layer the way I want them to.
Code below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="se">
<head>
<style>


.knap{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #161a20;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.knap::after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
height: 105%;
width: 105%;
border-radius: 200px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #008cff, #e100ff);
z-index: -1;
}

.wrap{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#b1{

margin-top: 50px;
z-index: 100;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
 <button class="knap" id="b1">About me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>


I have tried changing the z-index around, i have also tried to mess around in the wrapper div but nothing works afaik.

So why isn't the gradient applied to the <div>?  That's the container.

could you please elaborate on that, I want the button to look like this: https://ibb.co/2swT2HT



.knap{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #161a20;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #008cff, #e100ff);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    /* display: flex; */
    /* justify-content: center; */
    /* align-items: center; */
}

.knap::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* height: 105%;
  width: 105%; */
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 200px;
   background: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.knap::after {
  content: attr(data);
  /* background: linear-gradient(to left, #00FFA3, #DC1FFF);*/
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}


.wrap{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="se">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
 <button class="knap" id="b1">About me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>



You nearly had it, I think maybe the display: flex and the height and width of the .knap::before at 105% were throwing you off. The main .knap class didn't have any positive z-index on it, which helped. Here you go, I changed some values but commented out yours :)

@ZzzZ please be sure to mark this post as the correct answer so it is helpful for others.

You were so close. To make it work you just needed to add position: relative to .wrap. For the psuedo-element to be included in the stacking context its parent element must be positioned, then the only z-index you need is a -1 for the pseudo-element.
(I changed the height and width of the pseudo-element to px instead of % for even "border" thickness all around, and I also removed some unnecessary CSS properties.)


      .knap {
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        background-color: #161a20;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        position: relative;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .knap::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 60px;
        width: 260px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #008cff, #e100ff);
        z-index: -1;
      }
      .wrap {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
      }
      #b1 {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="knap" id="b1">About me</div>
    </div>



